# Using , separated in concat function in mysql query

Tags: mysql, laravel

Using this query, i will append the userid in table but it will insert in continuous i want to separated by , plz suggest change in query

```
 DB::table('table_user_create_activity')
               ->where(['activity_id'=>$query_get_activity->activity_id])
              ->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw('CONCAT(ifnull(accepted_join_id,""),'.$get_user_id.')')]);
```

Comment: Please make your questions clearer, what are the steps in detail?
Also some sample data would be helpful to understand where you are coming from and what the goal ist. Thanks!

Comment: @frankfurt-laravel actually i want to append value in table column like1,2,3 but my query will stored like123 plz suggest change in query.

Comment: *" i will append the userid in table but it will insert in continuous i want to separated by ,"* Good read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `DB::raw` SQL statement.
You are using MySQL `concat`, but that method does not add a separator.
For adding a separator use [`concat_ws`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/concat_ws/) (ws = with separator) and then the first argument is your separator.

```
->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(',', ifnull(accepted_join_id,''),".$get_user_id.')')])
```

A sidenote, your query is open for sql injections because of `$get_user_id` is added in the `DB::raw`. To close the sql injection change it to the following.

```
->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(',', ifnull(accepted_join_id,''),?)", [$get_user_id])])
```

This way we escape the user id before adding it in the query.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (`activity_id` = ?)' at line 1 (SQL: update `table_user_create_activity` set `accepted_join_id` = CONCAT_WS( where (`activity_id` = 7))

Comment: Btw your query is open for sql injections as `$get_user_id` is not escaped.

Comment: hello but it save like this format ,2,2 i want save like 2,2. When column contain null value it first save , then value like ,2,2

Comment: Try to remove the `ifnull` check, as `concat_ws` ignores null values.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This solves Your Problem

```
DB::table('table_user_create_activity')
    ->where([ 'activity_id' => $query_get_activity->activity_id ])
    ->update([
        'accepted_join_id' => DB::raw("CONCAT(ifnull(accepted_join_id,''), ',' , $get_user_id)")
    ]);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (`activity_id` = ?)' at line 1 (SQL: update `table_user_create_activity` set `accepted_join_id` = CONCAT(ifnull(accepted_join_id,""), where (`activity_id` = 7))

Answer (score 0):

DB::table('table_user_create_activity')->where(['activity_id'=>$query_get_activity->activity_id])->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw('CONCAT(ifnull(NULL,accepted_join_id),'.$get_user_id.')')]);